# How can I get a shutter signl of the Matrice 600 (PRO) A3?

Tags: dji-sdk

I have an M600 PRO (A3) and I need to connect an Arduino to it to receive a drone shutter.
In fact, I would like to use Drone Deploy with a photo of each waypoint and at the time of each photo I would like my arduino to receive this signal to perform a specific task. I have no camera attached to the drone.
Could someone help me with this task? I've already been able to connect A3 to the Arduino. I still can not understand the data bus fault.

i already connect one Arduino to the DJI MAtrice 600 Pro, but I do not found the hexa-Code related with shutter sign

I would like to receive the shutter sign from Matrice 600 in my Arduino, in order to program a special task related with this sign.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you want to use Drone Deploy, you won't be able to use the Mobile SDK and will need to build something with the Onboard SDK. It's unclear what you want since you say you have no camera but want to trigger something every time a picture is taken.

If you just want to detect when Drone Deploy tries to take a picture, you may get an error depending on if the sdk thinks there is a camera detected or not. I haven't tried the Onboard SDK much or especially tried without a camera attached so I don't know if an error will result or if you can set the trigger in the take picture callback.

Either way the best place to start is probably the [Camera sample onboard sdk app](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/sample-doc/camera-gimbal-control.html).